# Regex multiple replace with capture group and negated character class

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a problem with a regex and I cannot figure out if what I'm doing is possible. I was trying to write a regex to replace some strings with the following code

```
String string = "address='21 Street' and country='United Kingdom'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" (address|country)='[^']'");
String replacedString = pattern.matcher(string).replaceAll(" $1='call us'");

System.out.println(replacedString);
```

What I'm expecting is to print the string

```
address='call us' and country='call us'
```

I'm not going to end up implementing this with a regex, as there are other better ways, but I just want to know why this is not working :'(.

What confuses me is that the negated character class `[^']` is does not *"work"* and the regex doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `[^']*` and not `[^']`. The former matches any number of characters, the latter matches exactly a single non-`'` character.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quantifier. By itself, a character class matches exactly one character in the input string, so you need to specify a quantifier of some sort make it match more than one character.

Try adding a `+` (one or more) or `*` (zero or more) after your character class:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" (address|country)='[^']*'");
```